# JavaScript JQuery array loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

please, can someone help me with my looping array?
For some madness I can't get it to loop, I know this must be simple any ideas what I have missed.

Many thanks

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('#display').html('<p> Price: ' + data.results[i].value_inc_vat + '</p>');
  $('#display').append('<p> Time : ' + data.results[i].valid_from + '</p>');
  $('#display').append([i]);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looping correctly. The issue is because you're using `html()` which completely overwrites all existing content in the element. Therefore with each successive iteration you're removing the previously appended content.
To fix this, change `html()` to `append()`:

```js
let data = {
  results: [{
    value_inc_vat: 'value_inc_vat1',
    valid_from: 'valid_from1'
  },{
    value_inc_vat: 'value_inc_vat2',
    valid_from: 'valid_from2'
  }]
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  $('#display').append('<p> Price: ' + data.results[i].value_inc_vat + '</p>');
  $('#display').append('<p> Time : ' + data.results[i].valid_from + '</p>');
  $('#display').append([i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

It's also worth noting that you can use `map()` to build an array of strings which you can then `append()` only once to improve performance. Try this:

```js
let data = {
  results: [{
    value_inc_vat: 'value_inc_vat1',
    valid_from: 'valid_from1'
  },{
    value_inc_vat: 'value_inc_vat2',
    valid_from: 'valid_from2'
  }]
}

var html = data.results.map(function(result) {
  return '<p>Price: ' + result.value_inc_vat + '</p><p>Time : ' + result.valid_from + '</p>';
  
  // interpolated string version, note this won't work in IE:
  //return `<p>Price: ${result.value_inc_vat}</p><p>Time : ${result.valid_from}</p>`;
});
$('#display').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, that great thank your for all you help.. its was just missing .html to .append.

Answer (score 0):

Note:-This answer is based on your question. array is generated by me.
I think code is working correctly & the issue is with [html()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) which removes old HTML and append new HTML and you need to just replace `html()` with [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) will append new HTML codes.

```js
let data = {
  results: [{
    value_inc_vat: '1',
    valid_from: 'Today'
  }]
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
  $('#display').append('<p> Price: ' + data.results[i].value_inc_vat + '</p>');
  $('#display').append('<p> Time : ' + data.results[i].valid_from + '</p>');
  $('#display').append([i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sir, Okay. :-)

Comment: @CrutchMaster then what is a good idea..? Please let me know so, I can apply.

Comment: let div = $('#display'), then use this div in loop.